# Gradient of squared Frobenius norm

Tags: matrices, derivatives, normed-spaces, matrix-norms, scalar-fields

I would like to find the gradient of $\frac{1}{2} \big \| X A^T \big \|_F^2$ with respect to $X_{ij}$. Going by the chain rule in the Matrix Cookbook (eqn 126), it's something like

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X_{ij}} \Big[\frac{1}{2} \big\| X A \big\|_F^2 \Big] = \text{Tr} \Big[(XA^T)^T (J^{jk} A^T) \Big]$$

where $J$ has same dimensions as $X$ and has zeros everywhere except for entry $(j,k)$. I m not so sure about the $J^{jk} A^T$ bit (Cookbook eqn 66 applies here?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that if $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ then
\begin{equation}
\langle A, B \rangle = \text{Tr}(A^T B)
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{align*}
\|A\|_F^2 &= \langle A,A \rangle \\
&= \text{Tr}(A^T A) \\
&= \text{Tr}(A A^T).
\end{align*}

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that 
\begin{align*}
f(X) &= \frac12 \| X A^T \|_F^2 \\
&= \frac12 \text{Tr}(X A^T A X^T).
\end{align*}
Let $J$ be the $m \times n$ matrix whose entries are all $0$ except $J_{ij}$ which is equal to $1$.
Let $\Delta X = \epsilon J$, where $\epsilon > 0$ is tiny.

Then

\begin{align*}
f(X + \Delta X) &= \frac12 \text{Tr}((X + \Delta X)A^T A (X + \Delta X)^T) \\
&= \frac12 \text{Tr}(X A^T A X^T) + \frac12 \text{Tr}(\Delta X A^T A X^T)
+ \frac12 \text{Tr}(X A^T A \Delta X^T) \\
& \qquad + \frac12 \text{Tr}(\Delta X A^T A \Delta X^T) \\
&\approx \frac12 \text{Tr}(X A^T A X^T) + \frac12 \text{Tr}(\Delta X A^T A X^T)
+ \frac12 \text{Tr}(X A^T A \Delta X^T) \\
&= \frac12 \text{Tr}(X A^T A X^T) + \text{Tr}(X A^T A \Delta X^T) \\
&= f(X) + \left\langle X A^T A,\Delta X \right\rangle \\
&= f(X) + \epsilon \left \langle X A^T A,J \right\rangle.
\end{align*}

Comparing this result with the equation
\begin{equation}
f(X + \epsilon J) \approx f(X) + \epsilon \frac{\partial f(X)}{\partial X_{ij}}
\end{equation}
we see that 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f(X)}{\partial X_{ij}} = 
\left \langle X A^T A,J \right\rangle.
\end{equation}

Comment: thanks, I think there's a mistake in the second line of f(X + delta X), where the first term should be 1/2 Tr(X A^T A X^T) to match your definition of the Frobenius norm in terms of trace earlier.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I fixed it, but let me know if you see any other errors.

Comment: Why do you say that all entries of J are zero and then say that all entries (J_ij) are 1? Or did you mean to say that the diagonal entries i.e. J_ii are 1?

Comment: @StephenTierney $J$ has only one nonzero entry -- namely, $J_{ij}$.  I'm viewing $i$ and $j$ as given, fixed indices, and we want to compute $\frac{\partial f(X)}{\partial X_{ij}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M=XA^T$, then taking the differential leads directly to the derivative 
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \frac{1}{2}\,M:M \cr
df &= M:dM \cr
   &= M:dX\,A^T \cr
   &= MA:dX \cr
   &= XA^TA:dX \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= XA^TA \cr
}$$ 
Your question asks for the {$i,j$}-th component of this derivative, which is obtained by taking its Frobenius product with $J_{ij}$
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial X_{ij}} &= XA^TA:J_{ij} \cr
}$$ 
If you are unfamiliar with the Frobenius product, you can express the result in terms of the trace function instead, since $\,X\!:\!Y={\rm tr}(X^TY)$.

This yields the same result as you found using the Cookbook -- except you messed up your indices between the LHS {$ij$} and RHS {$jk$} for some inexplicable reason.