# Gradient of $\mbox{tr} \left (X^T X \right)$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

My goal is to compute

$$\frac{\mathrm{d} \operatorname{tr}\left(\mathbf{X}^{T} \mathbf{X}\right)}{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{X}}$$

Following the common way of approaching vector/matrix differentiation, I performed. entry-wise differentation as follows.

$$ 
d_{i j}=\frac{\partial \operatorname{tr}\left(\mathbf{X}^{T} \mathbf{X}\right)}{\partial x_{ij}}=\frac{\partial \sum_{k, l} x_{k l}^{2}}{\partial x_{ij}}=2 x_{ij} \rightarrow D=2X
$$

However, the answer is $D=2X^T$ with following computation.

$$
d_{i j}=\frac{\partial \operatorname{tr}\left(\mathbf{X}^{T} \mathbf{X}\right)}{\partial x_{j i}}=\frac{\partial \sum_{k, l} x_{k l}^{2}}{\partial x_{j i}}=2 x_{j i} \rightarrow D=2X^T
$$

I still can't understand why $d_{ij} = \frac{\cdot}{\partial x_{ji}}$ where order of $i$ and $j$ is switched.

Can anyone help me to understand the reason and know-how not to make a mistake afterward?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/229422/339790)

Comment: It turns out there are multiple [layout conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions) for derivatives with respect to a matrix. In the first, you used "denominator layout" and in the second "numerator layout." What reference are you following?

Comment: For example, in [The Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) they give $2\mathbf{X}$ for the derivative.

Comment: In my coursework, we follow the layout convention of "denominator".

Comment: Alternative approach using differentials. Let $f(X) := \rm{Tr}(X^T X) := X : X$. Then, using differential, $df(X) = X : dX + dX: X = 2X : dX$. The gradient is straightforward, that is, $\frac{\partial f (X)}{\partial X} = 2X$.

Answer (score 2):

Let [scalar field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_field) $f : \Bbb R^{m \times n} \to \Bbb R_0^+$ be defined by

$$f ({\bf X}) := \mbox{tr} \left( {\bf X}^\top {\bf X} \right) =: \| {\bf X} \|_{\text{F}}^2$$

The [directional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative) of $f$ at $\bf X$ in the direction of $\bf V$ is

$$\lim_\limits{h \to 0} \frac{f ({\bf X} + h {\bf V}) - f ({\bf X})}{h} = \dots = \langle {\bf V} , {\bf X} \rangle + \langle {\bf X} , {\bf V} \rangle = \langle {\bf V} , \color{blue}{2 {\bf X}} \rangle$$

where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denotes the [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product). Thus, the [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) of $f$ is

$$\nabla_{{\bf X}} f({\bf X}) = \color{blue}{2 {\bf X}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that matrices are a vector space with inner product $A:B:=A_{ij}B_{ij}=tr(A^TB)$.

Let $L(A)=tr(A^TA)$ then compute
\begin{align}
L(A+\delta B) &= tr((A+\delta B)^T(A+\delta B))\\
&=tr(A^TA)+\delta tr(B^TA)+\delta tr(A^TB)+\delta^2 tr(B^TB) \\ 
\end{align}
Derive respect $\delta$ and evaluate by $\delta=0$
\begin{align}
\frac{dL}{dA}:B:&=\frac{dL(A+\delta B)}{d\delta}\Big|_{\delta=0} = tr(B^TA)+tr(A^TB) \\&= B_{ij}A_{ij}+A_{ij}B_{ij} = 2A_{ij}B_{ij} = 2tr(A^TB) = 2A:B \quad \text{for all $B$}
\end{align}
Hence, $\frac{dL}{dA}=2A.$

Comment: Using your notation, don't you get that $\frac{dL}{dA}:B = 2A:B$ and not $2A^T:B$? It seems that the transpose slipped in when you temporarily went back to $2\operatorname{tr}(A^TB)$.

Comment: You right, I'm going to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Getting all the indices right for multidimensional derivatives can be tricky. Letting $D= \frac{d}{d\mathbf{X}} \operatorname{tr}(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})$, then the rule using the "denominator layout" is that $d_{ij}= \frac{d}{d x_{ij}} \operatorname{tr}(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})$.  This means that your second computation is for $d_{ji}$, not $d_{ij}$, so you do indeed get $D=2\mathbf{X}$ both times.